# neo4j community V1.9 - how to specify path of config files in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, configuration, neo4j

I need multiple neo4j embedded databases running on the same machine, on different ports.

I'm building on Spring -- how best to configure via Spring to do that? Ideally I want separate property files for each app, rather than baking the ports in the code -- e.g. /etc/app1.conf, /etc/app2.conf, and to be able to specify the relevant ports and other properties in those files.

I understand that such configuration was once possible in earlier versions of neo4j through a EmbeddedServerConfigurator class, which is no longer present in 1.8+

I'm running 1.9.5 with an eye to 2.0 in the nearish future, so a non-deprecated way of doing this would be much appreciated.

D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Darrell, if you run embedded there are no ports and no config files.

You just provide store-directories and optionally database config to your `GraphDatabaseService` instances which are (in Spring Data Neo4j) created as spring beans.

Unfortunately there is no compatible way between 1.9 and 2.0 as the public constructors of `EmbeddedGraphDatabase` were removed in 2.0 and I added a `GraphDatabaseServiceFactoryBean` in SDN 3.0 / Neo4j 2.0.

To run a server with an embedded Neo4j you'd probably have to go the way of extending `CommunityBootstrapper`. But here is no out of the box way integrating this in Spring right now.

So to make it work, I'd probably create a subclass of `CommunityBootstrapper` which starts the server, but can be passed in the `GraphDatabaseService` from the outside.

See my in-memory-server project for some hints: https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-in-memory-server

Comment: yes right you are of course, thanks Michael (brain fried by a 4 week old son... ;-)